# Enrichment of the pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have problem where the two csv file which has below columns

1st CSV

There are different producsts with different options

df1

| S. No. | Quantity | Product | Option | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | X | F1 | 100.0 |
| 2 | 1 | Z | G1 | 150.0 |

2nd CSV (Data from this needs to used to fill it in the first one)

df2

| Product | Option | Option | Buy_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | F1 | S1 | 80.0 |
| Z | G1 | H1 | 90.0 |

Tasks to fill the data from second file using the buy price and create another column with profit.

1. If the price for option is 0; buy price is 0
2. If there is match use that value
3. If there is no exact match use all options and use the mean value
4. If not exact match then 70% of the price

I am using the below logic. I have created a new column with Nan value

```
df1['profit'] = float('nan')
```

1. If the price value is 0 then change nan to 0

```py
df1.loc[df1['Price']<=0,'profit'] = 0.0
```

2. I have grouped the second csv with product and option and then iterated on each column to pop the value

```py
df2_gropued_P_O = df2.groupby(['Product','Option']).size().reset_index(name="Time")

for row in df2_gropued_P_O.iterrows():
  mean_sale = df2.loc[(df2['Product'] == row[1]['Product']) & (df2['Option'] == row[1]['Option']) & (df2['Price']>0)]['Price'].mean()
  df2.loc[(df2['Product'] == row[1]['Product']) & (df2['Option'] == row[1]['Option']) & (df2['Price']>0),['profit']] = mean_sale - row[1]['Buy_price']
```

3. I have grouped the second csv with options and then then iterated on each column to pop the value

```py
df2_gropued_O = fd2.groupby(['Option'])['Buy_price'].mean().reset_index()

option_intersect = set.intersection(set(df2_gropued_O['Option']),set(df1[df1['df2_gropued_O'].isna()]['Option']))

for i in options_intersect:
  df1.loc[(df1['profit'].isna()) & (df1['Option']==i),['profit']] = option_o_cost_gf.loc[option_o_cost_gf['Option']==i,['Buy_price']].values[0][0]
```

4. For all the remaning Nan Values use the price to fill value.

```py
for index in df2[df2['profit'].isna()].index.values.tolist():
  df2.loc[index,'profit'] = 0.70 * df2.loc[index,'Price']
```

If there any more efficient way to make it happen.

The step 4 is taking forever as number of left rows are around 650K.

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Anyway I can make the step 4 faster.

Comment: Have you made any attempt? You need to show your code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Reinderien is that alright? Please let me if there anything more I should add to it.

Comment: It's incomplete. You haven't shown `base_df`

Comment: And nowhere in your code do you show the 70% calculation

Comment: @Reinderien my bad. I have added everything requested.

Comment: And now `option_o_cost_gf` isn't defined. This isn't difficult: copy and paste the code into a fresh editor, and if it doesn't run, it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow.